# Building Mesa: clang-cpp not found

Tags: software-installation, mesa, clang

When building Mesa, I get this error when configuring the meson build:

```
Library clang-cpp found: NO
```

I tried to remedy with:

```
CC=clang-17 CXX=clang++-17 CPP=clang-cpp-17 meson setup
```

With same results.

I have:

```
$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
$ which clang-cpp
$ which clang-cpp-17
/usr/bin/clang-cpp-17
```

How can I make meson find clang-cpp-17 as the preprocessor?

OS: Ubuntu 24.04

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: It looks to me like it is a reference to a libclang *library*, rather than to a clang program. Perhaps you are missing the [libclang-cpp-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libclang-cpp-dev) package?

Comment: @steeldriver You nailed it. Thanks.